# Counting overlapping prescriptions in R

Tags: r

Firstly, I'm new to R and I apologize. So I'm working with data involving prescriptions. Since it's on a secure VM, I can't copy and paste, but the data structure looks like this:

Patient ID | Medication | Start Date | End Date

There are multiple rows for each patient, since each patient has been precribed more than one medication.

What I want to do is the following:
Find out how many medications/which medications the patients are on that overlap each other in terms of time frame, and then return how many overlapping prescriptions the patients has. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Nobody expects you to "copy and paste" confidential data. What you, just as anybody, can do is **construct** a dataframe that contains data similar to yours and that is similarly structured, and to present it so that it can easily be reproduced!

Comment: Further, if this were simply "how many meds at a time", then this is easier (and a duplicate). However, since you're looking for drug interactions (at least by time), then it becomes a bit hard to visualize what the output would look like. In addition to @ChrisRuehlemann's comment about providing fake data (e.g., `data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2), med=c('a','b','a','z'), ...)`), you will need to provide intended output given that sample input data. You will benefit from making the sample data representative-enough so that some things interact, some do not.